# Explicit Function for Bouncing Ball

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, collision, projectile

I was wondering if it's possible (and if so, how would you go about it) to write an explicit function for the position of a ball bouncing as a function of time (assuming a coefficient of restitution 0 < e < 1). It's certainly possible to find its location in time iteratively with small time steps, but I'm looking for a more elegant solution (i.e. can we write `y(t) = ?` and then plot just that function to see several bounces?). It seems challenging because you need some kind of periodic behavior, but the period changes with each bounce. I'm trying to do this *without* piecewise functions.

Let's consider just the one-dimensional case here, where the ball bounces straight up and down.

Note that I don't mean just calculate the enveloping function of its height like [this](http://feucht.us/writings/bouncing_ball.php)...I think this is related to the solution I'm after, but not the whole thing.

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please note that Physics.StackExchange is not a homework help site. Please read [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093).

Comment: @KyleKanos Thanks for linking me to those guidelines. This was an optional homework problem, but I asked the question (and further questions in the comments) with the intent of better understanding the solution, not just to get another poster to answer a homework question exactly as it appears. If this is still an inappropriate post, please let me know and I can remove my comments.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assume that after each bounce the velocity decreases in a factor $\xi\in(0,1)$. This means: if the velocity before hitting the floor is $\dot y$, then the velocity after hitting it will be $\xi \dot y$.

Let $y(0)=0$ be the initial height and $\dot y(0)=v_0$ be the initial velocity. We choose the units so that $g=1$ and $v_0=1/2$, where $g$ is the gravitational acceleration.

Define
$$
k(t)=\left\lfloor\log_\xi\!\bigg((\xi-1)t+1\bigg)\right\rfloor
$$
where $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ is the [floor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) ($k(t)$ is just the number of bounces after a time $t$)

With this, the height at a time $t$ is given by
$$
y(t)=\frac{1}{2}\xi^{k(t)}\left(t-\frac{\xi^{k(t)}-1}{\xi-1}\right)-\frac{1}{2}\left(t-\frac{\xi^{k(t)}-1}{\xi-1}\right)^2
$$

For example, if we take $\xi=0.9$ we get
[image]

---

**Explanation**

I'm just using the basic formula
$$
y(t)=v\ (t-t_0)-\frac{1}{2}g(t-t_0)^2
$$
of parabolic motion. In this case, the initial velocity *of each bounce* is different, so $v=v(t)$. It is easy to see that before the first bounce we have $v=1/2$. After the first bounce we have $v=\xi/2$, then $\xi^2/2$, $\xi^3/2$, etc. In general, $v(t)=\frac{1}{2}\xi^k$, where $k$ is the number of bounces at a time $t$.

On the other hand, the time-origin $t_0$ also changes with time: before the first bounce we have $t_0=0$, after the first bounce, $t_0=1$, then $t_0=1+\xi$, $t_0=1+\xi+\xi^2$, etc. In general,
$$
t_0=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \xi^i=\frac{\xi^k-1}{\xi-1}
$$

---

In the general case $g\neq 1$, $v_0\neq 1/2$ the number $k(t)$ is
$$
k(t)=\left\lfloor\log_\xi\!\bigg((\xi-1)\frac{gt}{2v_0}+1\bigg)\right\rfloor
$$
so that
$$
y(t)=v_0\xi^{k(t)}\left(t-\frac{2v_0}{g}\frac{\xi^{k(t)}-1}{\xi-1}\right)-\frac{1}{2}g\left(t-\frac{2v_0}{g}\frac{\xi^{k(t)}-1}{\xi-1}\right)^2
$$

---

Minimal *Mathematica* code to plot $y(t)$ for $g=1$ and $v_0=1/2:

```
\[Xi]=.9;
k[t_]:=Floor[Log[\[Xi],(\[Xi]-1)t+1]]; 
y[t_]:=1/2\[Xi]^k[t](t-(\[Xi]^k[t]-1)/(\[Xi]-1))-1/2(t-(\[Xi]^k[t]-1)/(\[Xi]-1))^2
Plot[y[t],{t,0,4.2},PlotRange->All]
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks! I think I followed along with how this works for the most part, but I'm not sure how to modify this for an arbitrary velocity, gravity, and initial height. Would it become `y(t) = (v0^k)*(t - t0) - .5*g*(t - t0)^2` ? I'm not sure if I adapted the expression for v(t) correctly.

Comment: Also, how would your expression for t0 change for an arbitrary velocity, gravity, and height? I think that for the third bounce, for example, t0 = 1 + r + r^2 because of the nice units you've selected.

Answer (score 1):

It's a discontinuous process, since the coefficient of restitution is only needed when at the instant the ball hits the ground and bounces back up. You would need to look it as an iterative process.