# Bouncing ball with friction

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction, collision, computational-physics, software

I am trying to write freefem code (same language as c++) for a bouncing ball, but i am not able to notice the result of friction force. At each time the rigid ball hits the rigid ground , the horizontal velocity must be decreased. While i am trying.. the velocity is not decreased, it is still bouncing for a fixed hieght.

Any hint please, i will be thankfull for any indication that help me proceed in writing the code.

Comment: Modifications to the horizontal velocity won't alter the bounce height.
Each time the ball bounces multiply the vertical velocity by a factor <1 representing energy loss. Have friction act on the horizontal velocity for the duration of the bounce impulse.

Comment: @JMLCarter I don’t know how i should apply friction at the moment of contact, this seems hard to be embedded in the code

Comment: I suppose if "rigid" you assume the contact duration is 1 time step.  The weight of the ball is increased over gravity by the reversal of velocity. Incorporate coefficient of friction and contact surface area into a single constant multiple of weight to produce a horizontal force. then F=ma horizontally

Comment: related: [Explicit Function for Bouncing Ball](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/245791/84967).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the simplest model would be to assume that the ball keeps a specified fraction, $\alpha$, of its kinetic energy on each bounce, say 90%, and to require that the tangent to the ball's path just before each bounce makes the same angle with the vertical (or the line perpendicular to the ground, if the ground is not level) as the tangent to the path just after the bounce.  That is, specify that the absolute value of the ratio of horizontal to vertical momentum is always constant when the ball is just above the ground.

This kinematic way of coming at it is more sensible than a dynamic method, I think: we don't really know what the force profile looks like during a bounce anyway. But if you want to specify forces and calculate a trajectory, you can get the same result by relating the frictional force to the normal force as follows:
$$\frac{F_{friction}}{F_{normal}}=\frac{1-\sqrt{\alpha}}{1+\sqrt{\alpha}}.$$

If you want to get more detailed, you can do calculations that include rotation of the ball and other factors, but I'd start with the above.